# Доступ к функциональности web-приложения с определённого места (локации)

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, администрирование

Есть windows-приложение на компьютерах сотрудников компании, позволяющее работать с базой данных web-приложения лишь в локальной сети офиса компании, и лишь тогда, когда запущен "главный компьютер" (главное приложение).

В общем приложение это умеет ещё много чего делать, но весь остальной функционал его уже переписан на web-приложение, в связи с чем встал вопрос о полном избавлении от программы, у которой остался лишь один плюс: контроль над сотрудниками, чтобы они могли работать с web-приложением только сидя в офисе.

**Так вот, каким(и) способом(ами) можно организовать это на web-сайте?**

Учитывая, что в офисе динамический IP-адрес!

Answer (score 1):

В данной ситуации возможны 2 более-менее надёжных варианта.

1. Если сервер с web приложением находится в той же сети, то можно
   разрешить доступ к нему только с внутренних адресов;
2. Если сервер с web приложением находится вне локальной сети, то создавать VPN. Далее см. п.1.

Как-то так...

Answer (score 0):

> чтобы они могли работать с web-приложением только сидя в офисе.

1. Настроить веб сервер на работу только по локальным IP
2. Если у вас веб сервер - apache - то можно создать в корне сайта файл .htaccess с диапазоном разрешенных IP (например 192.168.*.*)

   ```
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 192.168.*.*
   ```